# Show $M_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n-n\theta$ is a martingale w.r.t ${X_n}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Show $M_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n-n\theta$ is a martingale w.r.t ${X_n}$, given that $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\theta$

this is what I've done: $$\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|X_{\le n}]=\mathbb{E}[X_1+...+X_n+X_{n+i}-(n+1)\theta|X_{\le n}]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1+X_2+...+X_n-n\theta|X_{\le n}]+\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}-\theta|X_{\le n}]$$
$$M_n+\theta-\theta=M_n$$

is this correct?

Comment: I can understand your step and it is correct, but the notation/steps used looks quite weird to me. Also for a more rigorous answer you will want to state that the expectation is finite, although that is obvious.

Comment: Also consider the Doob-Meyer decomposition of $S_n := \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$.